# Does Spring MVC initialize all controllers on start up??

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, collections, controllers

Good day people. Right now in my web application I use a lot of Lists which will have to be sessionAttributes for my app. All this stored in one controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"institutionAttributes", "institutionTypeAttributes", "formDateAttributes", 
                        "formDescriptionAttributes", "deleteAttributesDescription", "deleteAttributesInstitution", "deleteAttributesDate"})
public class MainController {


    List<InstitutionInForm> listOfInstitutionsAttributes = new ArrayList<InstitutionInForm>();
    List<InstitutionTypeInForm> listOfInstitutionTypesAttributes = new ArrayList<InstitutionTypeInForm>();
    List<FormDate> listOfFormDateAttributes = new ArrayList<FormDate>();
    List<FormDescription> listOfFormDescriptionsAttributes = new ArrayList<FormDescription>();


    List<FormDescription> listOfFormDescriptionsDeleteAttributes = new ArrayList<FormDescription>();
    List<InstitutionInForm> listOfInstitutionDeleteAttributes = new ArrayList<InstitutionInForm>();
    List<FormDate> listOfDatesDeleteAttributes = new ArrayList<FormDate>();

//other methods omitted
```

Each of this Lists will initialize with initial value 10 and it takes some memory also. 
I decide to separate them by separating controllers.

So, I'm asking how it will initialize controllers all right on start up my application or when DispatcherServlet will get request from user, find a proper controller on after initialize them with all Lists inside.???

How can I prevent initializing don't needed at the moment controllers and Lists so on?

Thank you developers. Good productive coding day.

Comment: You should not worry about 7 empty Arraylists. As long as you not add objects, the memory consumption is quite low (in contrast to the complete spring application).  *Note: that a array (list), holds only references to the containing objects, not the objects itself*. If you are really really concerned about the 10 references, then you can initialize the array with an lower initial capaticity (but this has the drawback that when adding new objects the list needs to copy the internal array more often.)

Comment: Thanks Sir. I have question. Where all objects stored then if List contains only references?

Comment: Somewhere in the heap. -- But they are only stored in the heap after you create them. (and in your code you just create the lists but not the "objects")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use `@Lazy` to prevent eager loading/initialisation of your controller bean
This will get instantiated once first request comes.

```
@Lazy
@Controller
public class MainController { ...}
```

Comment: So and this also will initialize all lists of data inside controller?? Does it will stay alive after of will use sleep awake mode>?? Any ides how to make it??

Comment: Yes on initialization it will initialies all your lists but it will stay alive after that....your requirement sounds like you need to use [WeakHashMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html)  to access your list data

Comment: Thank's harrybvp for explanation