# How to get Spring MVC Controller to load lazily?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not able to get Spring MVC Controllers to lazy load.

I have tried the solution mentioned in [Does Spring MVC initialize all controllers on start up??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096860/does-spring-mvc-initialize-all-controllers-on-start-up/18097006#18097006)

Here is my code:

app-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc.controller">
```

AssetController.java

```
@Lazy(value=true)
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/asset")
public class AssetController{


  @Autowired
  private AssetService assetService;
```

What am I missing here?

Spring v3.0.7

Comment: is your bean `AssetController` referred somewhere, also possible to post more code for this class.

Comment: This was an example since, I cannot post the original code. But, I am pretty sure that `AssetController` is not being referenced from anywhere else since I am using `AssetController` as the REST Controller to my REST API.

Comment: does your bean `AssetController` has any postConstruct method also.

Comment: As far as I am aware it does not have any postConstruct.

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestMapping` annotation makes controller to be initialized eagerly despite the fact that it is also annotated with `@Lazy(value=true)`.

In your case, removing `@RequestMapping` annotation should make the controller initialize lazily. Though I do not know if it is possible to use `@RequestMapping` annotation and have that controller load lazily, I did not manage to achieve it (solved my issue without making the controller load lazily, but that is out of scope of this question).